# Get content from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables here.

```
Posts                        Comments
post_id                      comment_id 
content                      post_id                              
                             create_datetime
                             content
```

I have to write a SQL query that returns each post (sorted alphabetically by content) and its last comment.

It returns only 1 row (I have multiple posts) and the comment returned in the row is not the latest.

I have written this sql query :-

```
SELECT posts.content    AS post, 
       Max(Unix_timestamp(comments.create_datetime)), 
       comments.content AS comment 
FROM   posts, 
       comments 
WHERE  posts.post_id = comments.post_id
```

However, this doesn't do what is required..what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this doesn't do what is required.` isnt helpfull. Show us sample data, current and desire output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza
I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT posts.content    AS post, 
     t.create_datetime , 
     t.content AS comment 
FROM  posts
Inner Join  ( 
  select comments.content , comments.post_id , comments.create_datetime 
  from   comments 
  where ( comments.create_datetime,  comments.comment_id ) in 
    (select max(comments.create_datetime ), max(comments.comment_id) 
                    from comments 
                    group by comments.post_id ) ) t on t.post_id = posts.post_id;
```

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'comments.post_id ) ) t  
                     on t.post_id = posts.post_id
L' at line 10 `

Comment: I have check my answer and updated  .. be sure you don't have copied woen .. because in my answwr there is not the L char i see and the end of your comment

Comment: Still doesn't work.
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'comments.post_id ) ) t  
                     on t.post_id = posts.post_id
LIMI' at line 10 `

Comment: I have updated the asnwer  ... wrong tablename post instead od posts

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'comments.post_id ) ) t on t.post_id = posts.post_id
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 11 `

Comment: Update again missing "by" in group by .. hope

Answer (score 0):

You need get the max date first, and then fetch the comment.

```
SELECT post_id, MAX(create_datetime) as max_date
FROM Comments
GROUP BY post_id
```

fetch

```
SELECT C.post_id, C.content  
FROM Comments C
JOIN (SELECT post_id, MAX(create_datetime) as max_date
      FROM Comments
      GROUP BY post_id
     ) T
  ON C.create_datetime = T.max_date
```

NOTE: You have to be carefull if ties are possible

Comment: Error :- `#1054 - Unknown column 'T.create_datetime' in 'on clause' `

Comment: fixed was `ON C.create_datetime = T.max_date`

Answer (score -1):

Try to utilize relationships by reducing redundancy. Within your database structure your `Comments` table currently holds enough data to disregard the `Posts` table completely. This will also create anomalies.

So think about how `posts_id` and `content` are in both tables. You want a common field to relate the tables but you do not want to place an entire tables contents into another table to make it relatable.

[Database Redundancy and Normal Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa200276(v=office.11).aspx#ch04_redundancy)